# Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015' on yarn start

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I got some errors when run **yarn start** in ReactJS app, anyone can help please?

```
ERROR in ./main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015'
```

Belows are the information of config files:
The package.json:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.25.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

And the .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/react"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I got my answer: Edit the presets in **webpack.config.js** file the same as **.babelrc** file

```
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { // <-- Sometimes you should change it from query to options to avoid error
               presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'] // <-- Edit here
            }
         }
      ]
   },
```